# How do i use R htmlwidgets to display javascript clickable button in jupyter notebook

Tags: javascript, r, jupyter, jupyter-notebook, htmlwidgets

Here is a link to the htmlwidgets page [htmlWidgets](http://www.htmlwidgets.org/develop_intro.html)

There is a basic example using a sigma library and I was able to get that working but its not making sense to me on how I can use this library to do my own jupyter javascript based widgets.

Here is the basic example of making your own widget:

```
devtools::create("mywidget")               # create package using devtools
setwd("mywidget")                          # navigate to package dir
htmlwidgets::scaffoldWidget("mywidget")    # create widget scaffolding
devtools::install()                        # install the package so we can try it


library(mywidget)
mywidget("hello, world")
```

I have tried making my own widget from the basic example but have no clue how to modify the basic example in order to move forward with making a javascript clickable button in a Jupyter notebook.

Any help whether it is a video or link to something I can read to help me get going would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I am trying to do something similar...there are examples available online, the htmlWidgets page might be helpful. http://www.htmlwidgets.org/develop_intro.html#example-sigma.js

Answer (score 1):

The next version of the irkernel (>0.6) and the repr (>0.4) package includes integration with htmlwidgets: as long as the returned object is of class `"htmlwidget"` (`class(mywidget("hello, world"))` includes "htmlwidget"), it will be displayed as html in the notebook. If you install these two packages from github (`install_github("irkernel/repr"); install_github("irkernel/IRkernel")`), this should work out of the box.